# Problema con bucle do while en JAVA

Tags: java, while

Tengo el siguiente buce do while:

```
ArrayList<String> nombreP = new ArrayList();
ArrayList cantidadP = new ArrayList();
do{
        System.out.println("Producto?: ");
        nombreP.add(i, sc.nextLine());

        if(nombreP.get(i).equals("")){
            System.out.println("Compra terminada");
            break;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Unidades?: ");
            cantidadP.add(i, sc.nextInt());
        }
        i++;
    }while(!(nombreP.get(i-1).equals("")));
```

El problema es que se ejecuta 1 vez y cuando va por la segunda ejecución, aparece Producto? Compra terminada. Quiero suponer que está asignando el "intro" de Unidades? a la entrada de la segunda ejecución, y que por eso entra en el if y sale con el break, pero no se como arreglarlo.
Gracias.

Comment: @sstan, como puedo solventar ese posible duplicado?

Comment: @Sr1871 Puede ser, pero entonces no podría salir del bucle do while cuando producto es igual a la cadena vacía

Comment: Vale, he encontrado en la comunidad inglesa que se puede arreglar (de manera un poco chapucera) añadiendo un sc.nextLine() despues del sc.nextInt(), porque como bien ha dicho @sstan, hay problemas cuando se juntan estos dos metodos.

Answer (score 0):

Hice unas ligeras modificaciones a tu idea. Pero aqui tengo tu respuestas de una forma simple.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> productos = new HashMap<>(); // tabla de productos
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  String idProducto = "";
  String cantidad  = "";
  int i = 0;

while(true){ //Mientras halla espacio en el registro
    System.out.println("Producto?: ");
    idProducto = sc.nextLine(); // se guarda temporalmente la id del producto

    System.out.println("Unidades?: ");
    cantidad = sc.nextLine(); // se guarda la cantidad temporalmente

    if(idProducto.length() == 0 || cantidad.length() == 0) // evaluando que se no se imcumpla los requisitos
        break; // se termina el ciclo
    else { // en caso de que todo este bien
        productos.put(Integer.valueOf(idProducto), Integer.valueOf(cantidad));  // se almacena definitivamente los parametros
    }

    i++;
}

// Imprimimos el Map con un Iterador
Iterator it = productos.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
  Integer key = (Integer) it.next();
  System.out.println("id: " + key + " -> cantidad: " + productos.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hice esta solución:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<String, Integer> productos = new HashMap<>();
    String nombre;
    int cantidad = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Producto?: ");
        nombre = sc.nextLine();

        if(nombre.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Compra terminada.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unidades?: ");
            cantidad = Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine());
            productos.put(nombre, cantidad);
        }
    } while(!nombre.equals(""));

    Iterator n = productos.keySet().iterator();
    while(n.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) n.next();
        System.out.println("Nombre: " + key + " -> Cantidad: " + productos.get(key));
    }
```

Lo mejor es que siempre user nextLine() y le hagas un cast ya que las otras formas de capturar el dato no capturan el último caracter.